# IIS URL Rewrite for sub domains

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to set up a URL Rewrite in IIS, which will take a request that is coming from the root https://www.test.com redirects to https://www.test.com/nfc/ but, not redirect the request when the subdomain is 'app' (e.g. https://app.test.com).

I've configured the IIS rewrite script with following attributes:

Request URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Regular Expression
Pattern: ^$
Condition: {HTTP_HOST} Does Not Match the pattern ^app.test.com$
Action Type: Redirect
Redirect URL: /nfc/
Redirect Type: 307

Will there be a possibility of a recursive redirect that crashes the request.
[Here are the IIS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DThmE.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your rule, you can try this rule:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
               <conditions>
                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^app.test.com$" negate="true"/>
               </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/nfc" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: But what if the subdomain is 'app' (I do not want it to redirect in the case of app.test.com).

Comment: I edited my answer, you can try using the [negate attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-pattern-properties) to make it not match the subdomain.

Comment: Thanks (that's what I ended up doing as well).  Any chance of this rule creating an infinite loop?

Comment: What does "infinite loop" mean? Can you give an example?